# Dexextreme dxScheduler loading data multiple times

Tags: angular, devextreme

When the app first enters my view containing the scheduler, I create a custom datastore for the scheduler.  However the load: property is calling my getData() method 5 times on every load, by calling dxScheduler _loadFromStore.

Does anyone know why the load is being called so many times or how to make it only call once on initial page load?

Comment: Can you create plunker to reproduce it?

Comment: That will be very difficult to do.  Does anyone know what events trigger a load?